# Vagrant set up with puPHPet seems to ignore my forwarded_port setting

Tags: vagrant, yaml, virtualbox, vagrantfile, puphpet

What I want to do is run 2 or more vagrant boxes simultaniously. Now the problem I have is that I get the warning "The forwarded port to 2222 is already in use
on the host machine". This is wierd for I haven't set any of the Vagrant boxes to port 2222 during the puPHPet setup.

Here are the concerning parts in my 2 config.yaml files:

```
vagrantfile-local:
    vm:
        box: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
        box_url: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
        hostname: ''
        memory: '1024'
        cpus: '1'
        chosen_provider: virtualbox
        network:
            private_network: 192.168.56.101
            forwarded_port:
                dL5if56LAPQo:
                    host: '6645'
                    guest: '22'
```

And

```
---
vagrantfile-local:
    vm:
        box: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
        box_url: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
        hostname: ''
        memory: '1024'
        cpus: '1'
        chosen_provider: virtualbox
        network:
            private_network: 192.168.56.102
            forwarded_port:
                dL5if56LAPQo:
                    host: '6646'
                    guest: '22'
```

I'm guessing it's my fault but I don't see the port 2222 assigned anywhere (probably it's default).

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit of a cheat and it doesn't solve the core problem, but it's good enough for me. What I did to solve the problem was change the Vagrant file that puPHPet generated. I changed the forwarded ports line to:

```
data['vm']['network']['forwarded_port'].each do |i, port|
    if port['guest'] != '' && port['host'] != ''
      config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: port['guest'].to_i, host: port['host'].to_i, auto_correct: true
    end
  end
```

I added ", auto_correct: true". This is what the Vagrant documentation says about auto_correct:

---

**PORT COLLISIONS AND CORRECTION**

It is common when running multiple Vagrant machines to unknowingly create forwarded port definitions that collide with each other (two separate Vagrant projects forwarded to port 8080, for example). Vagrant includes built-in mechanism to detect this and correct it, automatically.

Port collision detection is always done. Vagrant will not allow you to define a forwarded port where the port on the host appears to be accepting traffic or connections.

Port collision auto-correction must be manually enabled for each forwarded port, since it is often surprising when it occurs and can lead the Vagrant user to think that the port wasn't properly forwarded. Enabling auto correct is easy:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080,
    auto_correct: true
end
```

The final :auto_correct parameter set to true tells Vagrant to auto correct any collisions. During a vagrant up or vagrant reload, Vagrant will output information about any collisions detections and auto corrections made, so you can take notice and act accordingly.

---

I couldn't have explained it better :)